# Generalization of de Rham cohomology, or cohomology for non-smooth case

Tags: cohomology, derham-cohomology

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a contractible region and $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a vector field on $f$. If $f$ is smooth vector field and $\nabla\cdot f=0$, then $f=\nabla\times g$ for some smooth vector field $g:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ by de Rham's theorem. ($\because H_{dR}^{2}(\Omega)=H^{2}(\Omega)=0$)

But recently, I heard that this result does not holds for **non-smooth** vector fields in general. In 2007, theorem 4.1 of [this paper (Brezis and Schaftingen, Boundary estimates for elliptic systems with L1–data)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-007-0094-9) shows that if $\Omega$ is contractible region in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $f$ is vector field on $\Omega$ with $\nabla\cdot f=0$ (here $f$ is not necessarily smooth). Then if $f$ is $L^{1}$, there exists (unique) $g\in L^{3/2}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{3})$ s.t. $f=\nabla\times g$.

Actually, I have 2 questions :

> 1. Is there any non-smooth vector field on simply-connected domain s.t. $\nabla\cdot f=0$ but $f=\nabla\times g$ does not have a solution?

> 2. Is there any cohomology theory that considers non-smooth vector fields? (for example, $C^{k}$ vector fields for some $k\geq 0$?)

Thanks!

Comment: de Rham considered a generalization for currents= distributional valued forms. You can look at his book. By the way, in your first paragraph $H^2(\Omega)=0$ will not follow from it being simply connected.

Comment: @DonuArapura I edited it. Thank you. (Maybe I confused with 2-dimensional case) By the way, can you tell me the name of the book? I can't find it...

Comment: Have you heard about the Dirac string and topological charges? It looks similar to your description. It certainly can be treated using Dirac delta distributions. Anyway it's always possible to substitute a topological charge by a hole (you just put a hole where things goes to infinity).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: de Rham, "Variétés différentiables. Formes, courants, formes harmoniques" or the English version "Differentiable manifolds. Forms, currents, harmonic forms"

Comment: @Seewoo Lee: That are very interesting questions. I wonder myself, if there are generalizations of de Rham's theorem to non-smooth forms. Unfortunately, the link to the paper in your post doesn't work any more. Could you please, provide the name of the author and/or title of it. Thanks!

Comment: @tj_ I updated the link! (I though I lost it but find the paper by reverse engineering the link :D)